# can't view `split` output files with cat

Tags: linux, command

File `a.txt` contains:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
```

Then the command: `split -2 a.txt output_` yields as output three new files `output_aa`, `output_ab`, `output_ac`

When I type: `cat output_aa` I received a message: `no such file or directory`.

But I can view `output_aa` in gedit.

Why?

Comment: I've tried your command on Fedora 14 and Ubuntu 12.10, works fine. I get 3 files (output_{aa,ab,ac}) with 2 lines in each.

Comment: Works on my mac too.

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo somewhere. Use `ls` to see what files are there, and use `Tab` autocompletion to make sure they're typed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man split` says, in part:

> Output  fixed-size  pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...

where `PREFIX` is the last command line parameter (`output_`, in your case). So the output files would be named `output_aa`, `output_ab` and `output_ac` for three parts of two lines each.

This is also the behavior I am seeing.

So the reason you cannot read `output_a` is that it isn't there, unless you create it yourself separately.

**If you want your files to be named with only a single-letter prefix** and have already run split, you can rename them. Assuming bash, you can use its [variable mangling functionality](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) to remove the first character of the suffix. Note that this may create duplicates (it won't in this particular case, but it might in the general case):

```
for f in output*; do echo mv "${f}" "${f%a?}${f##output_?}"; done
```

The first part of the target name expression removes `a?` (where `?` is any one character) from the end of the file name, leaving the prefix only; the second part removes `output_?` (again where `?` is any one character) from the beginning and appends the remainder. The result is removing the first character of the suffix.

When you are satisfied that this does what you want, remove the `echo`.

**If you can live with re-running `split`**, GNU coreutils (8.5 at least) `split` has an option `--suffix-length` which allows you to specify the length of the suffix. Just add it to your command line with an appropriate value:

```
split -2 --suffix-length=1 a.txt output_
```

This gives `output_a`, `output_b` and `output_c`, as desired. Thanks to [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77941/split-doesnt-give-the-output-files-i-expect/77942?noredirect=1#comment114398_77942) for pointing this out.

Comment: @don_crissti Good catch, I missed that in the man page. Will add it to my answer.

Comment: sorry, I'm wrong, I typed missing character 'a', I haved edit them :)

Comment: @TrongKha Do try the exact steps that you outline in your question. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling I have fixed it. Please Help me :)

Comment: @TrongKha I just tried it, it's working great, and I can't see any reason why it wouldn't. The only *possible* explanation I can think of is that you are confused about which directory `split` places its output files in, but I tried a few permutations and I can't reproduce the issue you are having. In every case, split put the output files where indicated by `PREFIX` (I tried both the current directory and a relative path, with the input file in the current or some other directory). **Please** try your own instructions for repeating the problem and update your question with the results.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling I don't know what's wrong with it, I tried it on different distro. and it's working great. I can't understand.